# ContentResolver.requestSync is working but ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync is not working

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

What could be the issue if ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync  is not triggering onPerformSync(...) method.

But ContentResolver.requestSync is triggering onPerformSync(...)

**More Info:** onPerformSync - just creates a notification.
And here is the code:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);

ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            ACCOUNT,
            AUTHORITY,
            null,
            SYNC_INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically with true as the third (sync) parameter to enable syncing for your adaptor.

Also, `Bundle` can't be null.  Use `new Bundle()` instead if you have no extras.

See [here](http://digitalassassin.net/2014/03/contentresolver-addperiodicsync-doesnt-work-never-syncs/)

Comment: Bundle.EMPTY is a better approach

Comment: It works on my device; but at the client. At some Samsung tablets the sync won't show up and never happens.